# Como alterar o formato da data para o between funcionar

Tags: php, sql-server, data

Eu tenho um form type date , que me retorna valores do tipo 2019-10-24 , contudo no meu banco está gravado como 20191024 , isso implica em que caso o usuário coloque numa busca duas datas iguais meu between não funcione . Contundo caso ele bote datas diferentes ele funciona.

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM TESTTE WHERE DT_EMISSAO BETWEEN '$data_inicial' AND '$data_final' ORDER BY FILIAL");
```

Answer (score 1):

O que eu fiz e resolveu :

```
$data_inicial = explode('-', $data_inicial);     // transforma em array
$data_inicial = implode('', $data_inicial);     // transforma em string novamente
$data_final = explode('-', $data_final);     // transforma em array
$data_final = implode('', $data_final);     // transforma em string novamente
```

Comment: Um link que talvez possa te ajudar: http://www.consultoriadba.com/post/2017/08/23/fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-data-no-sql-server e este envolvendo com PHP http://www.devwilliam.com.br/php/10-funcoes-php-trabalhar-data-e-hora